# Compose request for ServiceStack REST method using fiddler

Tags: rest, servicestack, fiddler

I am able to test the web services by setting Content-Type : "application/json" and passing parameters or composing body, for ex: {"name":"test"}, using fiddler. But, how to compose request for XML content type for a POST method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you'd set the **Content-Type** to **application/xml** and use XML to format the request body. e.g. test although the format would depend on what the API expects.